# What does the asterisk '*' in a build.gradle configuration mean?

Tags: gradle, groovy, configuration, proto

What does the asterisk in this gradle configuration mean? (from https://github.com/envoyproxy/protoc-gen-validate)

```
generateProtoTasks {
        all()*.plugins {
            javapgv {
                option "lang=java"
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is another usage of this block but without the asterisk (from https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin)

```
generateProtoTasks {
    all().each { task ->
      task.builtins {
        java {
          option "lite"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

`*.` is Groovy's [spread-dot operator](https://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_spread_operator). From the documentation:

> The Spread-dot Operator (`*.`), often abbreviated to just Spread Operator, is used to invoke an action on all items of an aggregate object. It is equivalent to calling the action on each item and collecting the result into a list:
>
> ```
> class Car {
>     String make
>     String model
> }
> def cars = [
>        new Car(make: 'Peugeot', model: '508'),
>        new Car(make: 'Renault', model: 'Clio')]       (1)
> def makes = cars*.make                                (2)
> assert makes == ['Peugeot', 'Renault']                (3)
> ```
>
> **1**build a list of `Car` items. The list is an aggregate of objects.**2**call the spread operator on the list, accessing the `make` property of each item**3**returns a list of strings corresponding to the collection of `make` items
>
> The expression `cars*.make` is equivalent to `cars.collect{ it.make }`. Groovy’s GPath notation allows a short-cut when the referenced property isn’t a property of the containing list, in that case it is automatically spread. In the previously mentioned case, the expression `cars.make` can be used, though retaining the explicit spread-dot operator is often recommended.
>
> -- https://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_spread_operator

Comment: That’s exactly what I was looking for, thanks!!

Comment: @AdiS if this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. Please nie that there is no obligation to do this.